# How to Update the old Values of one field into another field Value Using Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

**How to Update the old Values of one field into another field Value Using Process Builder**

Comment: Please Anyone Guide Me for the Answer

Comment: have you looked in `PRIORVALUE() ` function ?

Comment: Elavarasan... Does my ans helped ?

Comment: Elavarasan... I can see this question still open any reason.. It is best practice to closed the question by accept an answer.